# How would you write the equivalent of this C++ loop in Rust

Tags: loops, syntax, rust, iteration

Rust's `for` loops are a bit different than those in C-style languages. I am trying to figure out if I can achieve the same result below in a similar fashion in Rust. *Note the condition where the i^2 < n.*

```
for (int i = 2; i * i < n; i++)
{
    // code goes here ...
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can always do a literal translation to a `while` loop.

```
let mut i = 2;
while i * i < n {
    // code goes here
    i += 1;
}
```

You can also always write a `for` loop over an infinite range and break out on an arbitrary condition:

```
for i in 2.. {
    if i * i >= n { break }
    // code goes here
}
```

For this specific problem, you could also use `take_while`, but I don't know if that is actually more readable than breaking out of the for loop.  It would make more sense as part of a longer chain of "combinators".

```
for i in (2..).take_while(|i| i * i < n) {
    // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `take_while` suggestion from [zwol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52139943/493729) is the most idiomatic, and therefore usually the best choice. All of the information about the loop is kept together in a single expression instead of getting mixed into the body of the loop.

However, the *fastest* implementation is to precompute the square root of `n` (actually a weird sort of rounded-down square root). This lets you avoid doing a comparison every iteration, since you know this is always the final value of `i`.

```
let m = (n as f64 - 0.5).sqrt() as _;
for i in 2 ..= m {
    // code goes here
}
```

---

As a side note, I tried to benchmark these different loops. The `take_while` was the slowest. The version I just suggested always reported `0 ns/iter`, and I'm not sure if that's just due to some code being optimised to the point of not running at all, or if it really is too fast to measure. For most uses, the difference shouldn't be important though.

Comment: why did you put `-0.5` ? Are you sure it's safe with f64 accuracy ?

Comment: @Stargateur It's to ensure it always rounds down. The sqrt of a 9.0 could end up being slightly above or slightly below 3.0. At least this way, I know the answer is definitely 2.0.

Comment: "avoid doing a comparison every iteration" You mean multiplication, I think. You still have to compare on every iteration.

Comment: @trentcl It's both. This way it doesn't even need to compare `i` with `m`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I have learned more Rust since I wrote this answer.  This structure is still useful for some rare situations (like when the logic inside the loop needs to conditionally mutate the counter variable), but usually you'll want to use a Range Expression like zwol said.

---

I like this form, since it keeps the increment at the top of the loop instead of the bottom:

```
let mut i = 2 - 1;    // You need to subtract 1 from the initial value.
loop {
    i+=1; if i*i >= n { break }

    // code goes here...
}
```